# Bash script for multiple copy 1 file and rename to new name

Tags: bash, loops, copy

I want to create bash script for make multiple copy of 1 file in source directory to Destination directory and rename it with specific running number based on my config file.

example :Source directory --> /srv/test/ (have 3 type of file )

- **AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar**
- **AC-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar**
- **AD-BUG-K8000000000_20230908005727724.tar**

Destination directory --> /srv/rename

In my config file content of (copy from file name;Number of copy; New running number; Rename 2 front character)

config_rename.txt

- **AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar**;**2**;A1000000001;**12**
- **AC-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar**;**3**;B1000000009;**YX**

Expectation from the config file(config_rename.txt)

Destination directory --> /srv/rename Have 2 copy from this file **AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar** & rename it

- **12**-TEST-A10000000**01**_20230908005727724.tar
- **12**-TEST-A10000000**02**_20230908005727724.tar

Destination directory --> /srv/rename Have 3 copy from this file **AC-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar** & rename it

- **YX**-ERROR-B10000000**10**_20230908005727724.tar
- **YX**-ERROR-B10000000**11**_20230908005727724.tar
- **YX**-ERROR-B10000000**12**_20230908005727724.tar

I'm try to use this but not sure how to rename file it based on the config file

```
    cat $Conf_File | while read line
do
for file in "$Source_directory"/*; do 
 f="${file##*/}" 
[[ -f "$file" ]] && cp "$file" "$Destination_directory/$f"
done
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Adesoji Alu i have try & geeting this error
line 26: 10#A1000000001: value too great for base (error token is "10#A1000000001") line 26: 10#A1000000001: value too great for base (error token is "10#A1000000001")

In Destination directory --> /srv/rename only have this 1 file, if based on  config_rename.txt it should have 2 file                                                                      
 12-TEST-A1000000001__1.0_20231013005442590.tar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
f=(`ls test`)  #file array
r=(`cat config_rename.txt`)  #rule array

for((i=0;i<${#f[*]};i++))
do
  f0=${f[i]#*-}  #example: TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar
  f1=${f0%-*}  #type of file, example: TEST
  f2=${f[i]##*_}  #example: 20230908005727724.tar
  for((j=0;j<${#r[*]};j++))
  do
    r_tmp=(${r[j]//;/ })  #temp array, example: r_tmp=(AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar 2 A1000000001 12)
    f3=${r_tmp[2]%%[0-9]*}  #example: A
    f4=${r_tmp[2]##*[A-Za-z]}  #example: 1000000001
    if [[ ${f[i]} == ${r_tmp[0]} ]];then
      #while((r_tmp[1]--))
      for((k=0;k<${r_tmp[1]};k++))
      do
        f5=${f3}$((${f4}+k))
        cp test/${f[i]} rename/${r_tmp[3]}-${f1}-${f5}_${f2}
      done
    fi
  done
done
```

example:

```
$ find
.
./test
./test/AD-BUG-K8000000000_20230908005727724.tar
./test/AC-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar
./test/AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar
./rename
./a.sh
./config_rename.txt
$ bash a.sh && find
.
./test
./test/AD-BUG-K8000000000_20230908005727724.tar
./test/AC-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar
./test/AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar
./rename
./rename/YX-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar
./rename/YX-ERROR-B1000000011_20230908005727724.tar
./rename/YX-ERROR-B1000000010_20230908005727724.tar
./rename/12-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar
./rename/12-TEST-A1000000002_20230908005727724.tar
./a.sh
./config_rename.txt
$ cat config_rename.txt
AB-TEST-A1000000001_20230908005727724.tar;2;A1000000001;12
AC-ERROR-B1000000009_20230908005727724.tar;3;B1000000009;YX
```